# How do I get rid of the | and display the useradd command in my shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to bash and I'm trying to get the hang of it, I have a text file titled `cs.roster.txt` and the contents are right below:

```
   CMPSC 1513 03|smijoh|Smith, John|0510|/bin/bash
   CMPSC 1513 03|doejan|Doe, Jane|0510|/bin/bash
   CMPSC 1133 01|cp2stu3| CPII, Student3 Neither|0020|/bin/bash
   CMPSC 1003 01|staton|Stark, Tony|0510|/bin/bash
   CMPSC 4324 02|evachr|Evans, Chris|2323|/bin/bash
   CMPSC 3534 03|bromil|Brown, Millie|0510|/bin/bash
   CMPSC 1513 01|rocchr|Rock, Chris|4433|/bin/bash
```

What I'm trying to do is get rid of the '|' and replace them with ':' and then when I compile, it should read the the content in-between the ':' I've been working on this for a while but I can't seem to get my code to run properly. The code is posted below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  class_id=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'|' -f1)
  username=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'|' -f2)
  full=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'|' -f3)
  student_id=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'|' -f4)
  echo "adduser -g '$student_id' -s /bin/bash '$class_id'"
done < "cs.roster.txt"
```

I'm getting the error that is telling me that the home directory is invalid, can you help me get my code to run correctly?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that adds `:` Some of your data has 5 fields, some has 6.

Comment: I'm wanting to switch the | with : would that be possible (just like the /etc/passwd) and then display the command to add the user @jhnc

Comment: Any of `tr`, `awk` or `sed` will let you replace `|`.

Comment: You should put the exact error message (in code block) in the question, not a paraphrase. Anyway, there is nothing in the code you posted that would produce that message, so you should probably post the actual code that corresponds to it too.

Comment: neither your student_id nor your class_id is unique, so it is strange to try to create users with non-distinct names. Also, spaces are unusual in user and group names

Comment: _when I compile_  : I don't see any compilation going on (nor would I expect one). What do you mean here?

Comment: `$class_id` is == `cut -d'|' -f1`, which is the first field before the `|`.  So your user name has spaces.  Ex: `CMPSC 1513 03`.  `$username` is the variable you should be using.